# dropdown menu fails on just one domain

Tags: drop-down-menu

I have a drop-down menu that works off a script.js file on multiple websites.  It works on multiple domains, but recently it stopped working on one domain, and now I cannot get any script.js menu dropdowns to work on that domain.

What could be blocking the script from working?

Comment: Have you hit F12 and look in the console for errors?

Comment: I would also wonder if that domain no longer has access to some database that might be populating the dropdown box.  Just speculation of course.